# Fetch rows if the value is present in list of value in Dataframe's column. Pandas Dataframe column's values are in the list format

Tags: list, dataframe, scalar

Today, I have worked on a similar problem where I need to fetch rows containing a value we are looking for, but the data frame's columns' values are in the list format.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I have come up with.

`fetched_rows = df.loc [ df['column_name'].map( lambda  x : True if check_element in x else False) ==  True ]`

Where **column_name** ---> the column name that we need to look into

**check_element** ---> the value that we use to check whether it exists.